# Serialize Class containing Dictionary member

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, dictionary

Expanding upon my [earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489173/writing-xml-with-c), I've decided to (de)serialize my config file class which worked great.

I now want to store an associative array of drive letters to map (key is the drive letter, value is the network path) and have tried using `Dictionary`, `HybridDictionary`, and `Hashtable` for this but I always get the following error when calling `ConfigFile.Load()` or `ConfigFile.Save()`:

> There was an error reflecting type
>   'App.ConfigFile'. [snip]
>   System.NotSupportedException: Cannot
>   serialize member
>   App.Configfile.mappedDrives [snip]

From what I've read Dictionaries and HashTables can be serialized, so what am I doing wrong?

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Config")]
public class ConfigFile
{
    public String guiPath { get; set; }
    public string configPath { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> mappedDrives = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Boolean Save(String filename)
    {
        using(var filestream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            try
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigFile));
                serializer.Serialize(filestream, this);
                return true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addDrive(string drvLetter, string path)
    {
        this.mappedDrives.Add(drvLetter, path);
    }

    public static ConfigFile Load(string filename)
    {
        using (var filestream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            try
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigFile));
                return (ConfigFile)serializer.Deserialize(filestream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.ToString());
                return new ConfigFile();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can't serialize a class that implements IDictionary. Check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx).

> Q: Why can't I serialize hashtables?
>
> A: The XmlSerializer cannot process
>   classes implementing the IDictionary
>   interface. This was partly due to
>   schedule constraints and partly due to
>   the fact that a hashtable does not
>   have a counterpart in the XSD type
>   system. The only solution is to
>   implement a custom hashtable that does
>   not implement the IDictionary
>   interface.

So I think you need to create your own version of the Dictionary for this. Check this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959/c-xml-serialization-gotchas).

Comment: Just wondering the `DataContractSerializer` class can do that. Just the output is a bit ugly.

Answer (score 194):

There is a solution at [Paul Welter's Weblog - XML Serializable Generic Dictionary](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx)

> For some reason, the generic Dictionary in .net 2.0 is not XML serializable.  The following code snippet is a xml serializable generic dictionary.  The dictionary is serialzable by implementing the IXmlSerializable interface.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("dictionary")]
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public SerializableDictionary() { }
    public SerializableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary) : base(dictionary) { }
    public SerializableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(dictionary, comparer) { }
    public SerializableDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(comparer) { }
    public SerializableDictionary(int capacity) : base(capacity) { }
    public SerializableDictionary(int capacity, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(capacity, comparer) { }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

        bool wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
        reader.Read();

        if (wasEmpty)
            return;

        while (reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement("item");

            reader.ReadStartElement("key");
            TKey key = (TKey)keySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();

            reader.ReadStartElement("value");
            TValue value = (TValue)valueSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();

            this.Add(key, value);

            reader.ReadEndElement();
            reader.MoveToContent();
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

        foreach (TKey key in this.Keys)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("item");

            writer.WriteStartElement("key");
            keySerializer.Serialize(writer, key);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("value");
            TValue value = this[key];
            valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: +1 Fantastic answer. Also works for SortedList, just changed the "SerializableDictionary" to "SerializableSortedList" and the "Dictionary<TKey, TValue>" to "SortedList<TKey, TValue>".

Comment: Works great.  The answer accepted above quotes MS saying "The only solution is to implement a custom hashtable that does not implement the IDictionary interface".  But that's not true is it?  The above soltion inherits Dictionary (and therefore implments iDictionary) but also implements IXMLSerializable.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: I've added a adaptation of this class in my answer that uses attributes for key/value instead of elements.

Comment: +1 and one suggestion. When a SerializableDictionary object holds more than one elements, exception is thrown... ReadXml() and WriteXml() should be modified to move ReadStartElement("item"); and WriteStartElement("item"); and its associated ReadEndElement() and WriteEndElement() out of the while loop.

Comment: Does that then mean that in later frameworks the IDictionary is serializable?

Comment: This implementation will work if the dictionary is storing, say, `string` values, but will throw an `InvalidOperationException` on deserialization mentioning an unexpected wrapper element if you try storing custom objects or string arrays in it. (See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49368839/3775798) for an example of the issues I faced with this.)

Answer (score 60):

Instead of using `XmlSerializer` you can use a `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer`. This can serialize dictionaries and interfaces no sweat.

Here is a link to a full example, http://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/net-tips-xml-serialize-or-deserialize-dictionary-in-csharp/

Comment: Problem with DataContractSerializer is that it serializes and deserializes in alphabetical order so if you try to deserialize something in the wrong order it will fail silently with null properties in your object

Answer (score 18):

Create a serialization surrogate.

Example, you have a class with public property of type Dictionary.

To support Xml serialization of this type, create a generic key-value class:

```
public class SerializeableKeyValue<T1,T2>
{
    public T1 Key { get; set; }
    public T2 Value { get; set; }
}
```

Add an XmlIgnore attribute to your original property:

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Dictionary<int, string> SearchCategories { get; set; }
```

Expose a public property of array type, that holds an array of SerializableKeyValue instances, which are used to serialize and deserialize into the SearchCategories property:

```
    public SerializeableKeyValue<int, string>[] SearchCategoriesSerializable
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<SerializeableKeyValue<int, string>>();
            if (SearchCategories != null)
            {
                list.AddRange(SearchCategories.Keys.Select(key => new SerializeableKeyValue<int, string>() {Key = key, Value = SearchCategories[key]}));
            }
            return list.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            SearchCategories = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                SearchCategories.Add( item.Key, item.Value );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like this because it decouples serialization from the dictionary member.  If I had a heavily used class that I wanted to add serialization capabilities to, then wrapping the dictionary could cause a break with inherited types.

Comment: A word of caution for anyone implementing this: if you try to make your surrogate property a List (or any other *collection*), the XML serializer **won't call the setter** (instead it calls the *getter* and tries to add to the list returned, which obviously isn't what you wanted).  Stick to arrays for this pattern.

Answer (score 9):

You should explore Json.Net, quite easy to use and allows Json objects to be deserialized in Dictionary directly.

[james_newtonking](http://james.newtonking.com)

example:

```
string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json); 
Console.WriteLine(values.Count);
// 2
Console.WriteLine(values["key1"]);
// value1
```

Answer (score 7):

Dictionaries and Hashtables are not serializable with `XmlSerializer`. Therefore you cannot use them directly. A workaround would be to use the `XmlIgnore` attribute to hide those properties from the serializer and expose them via a list of serializable key-value pairs.

PS: constructing an `XmlSerializer` is very expensive, so always cache it if there is a chance of being able to re-use it.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted a SerializableDictionary class that used xml attributes for key/value so I've adapted Paul Welter's class.

This produces xml like:

```
<Dictionary>
  <Item Key="Grass" Value="Green" />
  <Item Key="Snow" Value="White" />
  <Item Key="Sky" Value="Blue" />
</Dictionary>"
```

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace DataTypes {
    [XmlRoot("Dictionary")]
    public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>
        : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable {
        #region IXmlSerializable Members
        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
            XDocument doc = null;
            using (XmlReader subtreeReader = reader.ReadSubtree()) {
                doc = XDocument.Load(subtreeReader);
            }
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>));
            foreach (XElement item in doc.Descendants(XName.Get("Item"))) {
                using(XmlReader itemReader =  item.CreateReader()) {
                    var kvp = serializer.Deserialize(itemReader) as SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>;
                    this.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                }
            }
            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }

        public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer) {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>));
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");
            foreach (TKey key in this.Keys) {
                TValue value = this[key];
                var kvp = new SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, kvp, ns);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        [XmlRoot("Item")]
        public class SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> {
            [XmlAttribute("Key")]
            public TKey Key;

            [XmlAttribute("Value")]
            public TValue Value;

            /// <summary>
            /// Default constructor
            /// </summary>
            public SerializableKeyValuePair() { }
        public SerializableKeyValuePair (TKey key, TValue value) {
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Unit Tests:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace DataTypes {
    [TestClass]
    public class SerializableDictionaryTests {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestStringStringDict() {
            var dict = new SerializableDictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("Grass", "Green");
            dict.Add("Snow", "White");
            dict.Add("Sky", "Blue");
            dict.Add("Tomato", "Red");
            dict.Add("Coal", "Black");
            dict.Add("Mud", "Brown");

            var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(dict.GetType());
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
                // Load memory stream with this objects xml representation
                XmlWriter xmlWriter = null;
                try {
                    xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, dict);
                } finally {
                    xmlWriter.Close();
                }

                // Rewind
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
                Assert.AreEqual("Dictionary", doc.Root.Name);
                Assert.AreEqual(dict.Count, doc.Root.Descendants().Count());

                // Rewind
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var outDict = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as SerializableDictionary<string, string>;
                Assert.AreEqual(dict["Grass"], outDict["Grass"]);
                Assert.AreEqual(dict["Snow"], outDict["Snow"]);
                Assert.AreEqual(dict["Sky"], outDict["Sky"]);
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestIntIntDict() {
            var dict = new SerializableDictionary<int, int>();
            dict.Add(4, 7);
            dict.Add(5, 9);
            dict.Add(7, 8);

            var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(dict.GetType());
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
                // Load memory stream with this objects xml representation
                XmlWriter xmlWriter = null;
                try {
                    xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, dict);
                } finally {
                    xmlWriter.Close();
                }

                // Rewind
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
                Assert.AreEqual("Dictionary", doc.Root.Name);
                Assert.AreEqual(3, doc.Root.Descendants().Count());

                // Rewind
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var outDict = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as SerializableDictionary<int, int>;
                Assert.AreEqual(dict[4], outDict[4]);
                Assert.AreEqual(dict[5], outDict[5]);
                Assert.AreEqual(dict[7], outDict[7]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good but it fails with an empty Dictionary.  You need the reader.IsEmptyElement test in the ReadXML method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ExtendedXmlSerializer](https://github.com/wojtpl2/ExtendedXmlSerializer). 
If you have a class:

```
public class ConfigFile
{
    public String guiPath { get; set; }
    public string configPath { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> mappedDrives {get;set;} 

    public ConfigFile()
    {
        mappedDrives = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

and create instance of this class:

```
ConfigFile config = new ConfigFile();
config.guiPath = "guiPath";
config.configPath = "configPath";
config.mappedDrives.Add("Mouse", "Logitech MX Master");
config.mappedDrives.Add("keyboard", "Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000");
```

You can serialize this object using ExtendedXmlSerializer:

```
ExtendedXmlSerializer serializer = new ExtendedXmlSerializer();
var xml = serializer.Serialize(config);
```

Output xml will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigFile type="Program+ConfigFile">
    <guiPath>guiPath</guiPath>
    <configPath>configPath</configPath>
    <mappedDrives>
        <Item>
            <Key>Mouse</Key>
            <Value>Logitech MX Master</Value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Key>keyboard</Key>
            <Value>Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000</Value>
        </Item>
    </mappedDrives>
</ConfigFile>
```

You can install ExtendedXmlSerializer from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedXmlSerializer/) or run the following command:

```
Install-Package ExtendedXmlSerializer
```

Here is [online example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SBwUfy)

Answer (score 2):

the Dictionary class implements ISerializable. The definition of Class Dictionary given below.

```
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView<,>))]
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
[Serializable]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false)]
public class Dictionary<TKey,TValue>: IDictionary<TKey,TValue>, IDictionary, IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback
```

I don't think that is the problem. refer to the below link, which says that if you are having any other data type which is not serializable then Dictionary will not be serialized.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1734187.aspx?Is+Dictionary+serializable+

Comment: That is true in the latest versions, but in .NET 2, Dictionary is not serializable, even today.  I confirmed it just today with a project targeting .NET 3.5, which is how I found this thread.

Answer (score 0):

This article explains exactly how to handle this:
[How do I... Serialize a hash table in C# when the application requires it?](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/howdoi/?p=143)

I hope this is helpful

Comment: Link-only answers are subject to bit rot, and should be summarized in the answer body itself with the essential details.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataContractSerialize of  System.Runtime.Serialization. This will able to serialize IDictionary and Dictionary members.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/datacontractserializer-sample

Find the code snippet below.

```
public  ConfigFile ExtractConfigFileFromXml(string xmlPath)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ConfigFile));
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, settings);
    var confile = (ConfigFile)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
    return confile;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the reference to Paul Welter's blog, here is an updated codeset compatible with the latest C# to handle nullable types (because, you know, I'm anal about writing code with no warnings!):

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Class borrowed from Paul Welter's blog https://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/444961
 * Thank you for your invaluable contribution!
 */

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace {Your-Namespace}
{

    [XmlRoot("dictionary")]
    public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>
        : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable
        where TKey : notnull
    {
        public SerializableDictionary() { }
        public SerializableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary) : base(dictionary) { }
        public SerializableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(dictionary, comparer) { }
        public SerializableDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(comparer) { }
        public SerializableDictionary(int capacity) : base(capacity) { }
        public SerializableDictionary(int capacity, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(capacity, comparer) { }

        #region IXmlSerializable Members
        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null!;
        }

        public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
        {
            XmlSerializer keySerializer = new(typeof(TKey));
            XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new(typeof(TValue));

            bool wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
            reader.Read();

            if (wasEmpty)
                return;

            while (reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                reader.ReadStartElement("item");

                reader.ReadStartElement("key");
                TKey key = (TKey)keySerializer.Deserialize(reader)!;
                reader.ReadEndElement();

                reader.ReadStartElement("value");
                TValue value = (TValue)valueSerializer.Deserialize(reader)!;
                reader.ReadEndElement();

                this.Add(key!, value!);

                reader.ReadEndElement();
                reader.MoveToContent();
            }
            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }

        public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
        {
            XmlSerializer keySerializer = new(typeof(TKey));
            XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new(typeof(TValue));

            foreach (TKey key in this.Keys)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("item");

                writer.WriteStartElement("key");
                keySerializer.Serialize(writer, key);
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("value");
                TValue value = this[key];
                valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```