# Serializing .NET dictionary

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serialize Class containing Dictionary member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495647/serialize-class-containing-dictionary-member)

Can I serialize a Dictionary?

Comment: Which serialization API? They will each be different...

Answer (score 20):

Which serialization API?

For example, `DataContractSerializer` can handle dictionaries, especially with the (optional) `[CollectionDataContract]` markup. protobuf-net will handle them (below). Others may not...

```
    var data = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    data.Add("abc", 123);
    data.Add("def", 456);

    var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(data);
    Console.WriteLine(clone["abc"]);
    Console.WriteLine(clone["def"]);
```

As will `BinaryFormatter`:

```
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(ms, data);
        ms.Position = 0;
        clone = (Dictionary<string, int>) bf.Deserialize(ms);
    }
```

Comment: +1. I was going to suggest DataContractSerializer as a possible serializer for Dictionary. It goes without saying that you'd also mention photobuf-net. :-).

Comment: JSON.Net can serialize Dictionaries as well, of course.

Answer (score 15):

Not without using another serialization library or implementing serialization yourself. Neither Hashtable or Dictionary are serializable out of the box in .NET.  There is an implementation of a SerializableDictionary [here](http://www.dacris.com/blog/2010/07/31/c-serializable-dictionary-a-working-example/) that does both XML and binary serialization.

Here is the code from the link (Copyright (c) Dacris Software Inc. MIT license):

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

[Serializable()]
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TVal> : Dictionary<TKey, TVal>, IXmlSerializable, ISerializable
{
        #region Constants
        private const string DictionaryNodeName = "Dictionary";
        private const string ItemNodeName = "Item";
        private const string KeyNodeName = "Key";
        private const string ValueNodeName = "Value";
        #endregion
        #region Constructors
        public SerializableDictionary()
        {
        }

        public SerializableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TVal> dictionary)
            : base(dictionary)
        {
        }

        public SerializableDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
            : base(comparer)
        {
        }

        public SerializableDictionary(int capacity)
            : base(capacity)
        {
        }

        public SerializableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TVal> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
            : base(dictionary, comparer)
        {
        }

        public SerializableDictionary(int capacity, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
            : base(capacity, comparer)
        {
        }

        #endregion
        #region ISerializable Members

        protected SerializableDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            int itemCount = info.GetInt32("ItemCount");
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
            {
                KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> kvp = (KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal>)info.GetValue(String.Format("Item{0}", i), typeof(KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal>));
                this.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
        }

        void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("ItemCount", this.Count);
            int itemIdx = 0;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> kvp in this)
            {
                info.AddValue(String.Format("Item{0}", itemIdx), kvp, typeof(KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal>));
                itemIdx++;
            }
        }

        #endregion
        #region IXmlSerializable Members

        void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
        {
            //writer.WriteStartElement(DictionaryNodeName);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> kvp in this)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement(ItemNodeName);
                writer.WriteStartElement(KeyNodeName);
                KeySerializer.Serialize(writer, kvp.Key);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteStartElement(ValueNodeName);
                ValueSerializer.Serialize(writer, kvp.Value);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            //writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
        {
            if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Move past container
            if (!reader.Read())
            {
                throw new XmlException("Error in Deserialization of Dictionary");
            }

            //reader.ReadStartElement(DictionaryNodeName);
            while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                reader.ReadStartElement(ItemNodeName);
                reader.ReadStartElement(KeyNodeName);
                TKey key = (TKey)KeySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
                reader.ReadEndElement();
                reader.ReadStartElement(ValueNodeName);
                TVal value = (TVal)ValueSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
                reader.ReadEndElement();
                reader.ReadEndElement();
                this.Add(key, value);
                reader.MoveToContent();
            }
            //reader.ReadEndElement();

            reader.ReadEndElement(); // Read End Element to close Read of containing node
        }

        System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        #endregion
        #region Private Properties
        protected XmlSerializer ValueSerializer
        {
            get
            {
                if (valueSerializer == null)
                {
                    valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TVal));
                }
                return valueSerializer;
            }
        }

        private XmlSerializer KeySerializer
        {
            get
            {
                if (keySerializer == null)
                {
                    keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
                }
                return keySerializer;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Private Members
        private XmlSerializer keySerializer = null;
        private XmlSerializer valueSerializer = null;
        #endregion
}
```

Comment: Would you be so kind as to copy the code from that link here?

Comment: Done, one less link to click.

Comment: @ScottLerch is this still true?