# Serializing a custom class to XML

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a class containing a `SortedList<string, Data>` as private field, where `Data` is a simple custom class with some `int`, `DateTime` and `Nullable<DateTime>` fields.

```
public class CustomCollection
{
    private SortedList<string, Data> _list;

    ...
}
```

Now I would make my class serializable, so I could write its content (ie the items of the `_list` field) in an XML file or load data from an existing XML file.

How should I proceed?

I think I understand that there are two ways to serialize: the first would be to mark all fields as serializable, while the second would be to implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface. If I understand correctly, when I can use each of the two ways?

Comment: Are you saying you want to load an xml representation of _list from an xml file and save it to an xml file?

Comment: @Ricky.G: Yes, both _load from_ and _save to_ an XML file.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164135.aspx may help. I will write some test source for you when I have time.

Comment: @findcaiyzh: +1 for the clear and interesting article!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, you just need to decorate your Classes with [Serializable] attribute and it should work.  However you have a SortedList which implements an IDictionary and these cant be serialized with the IXMLSerializable so need to do a bit of customization look here

[Serializing .NET dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299071/serializing-net-dictionary)

but if you change your sorted list to a normal list or anything that doesnt implement an IDictionary then the below code will work :-) copy it to a console app and run it.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Data d = new Data { CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now, DataId = 1 };
            Data d1 = new Data { CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now, DataId = 2 };
            Data d2 = new Data { CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now, DataId = 3 };

            CustomCollection cc = new CustomCollection
                                      {List = new List<Data> {d, d1, d2}};

            //This is the xml
            string xml = MessageSerializer<CustomCollection>.Serialize(cc);

            //This is deserialising it back to the original collection
            CustomCollection collection = MessageSerializer<CustomCollection>.Deserialize(xml);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Data
    {
        public int DataId;
        public DateTime CurrentDateTime;
        public DateTime? CurrentNullableDateTime;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class CustomCollection
    {
        public List<Data> List;
    }

    public class MessageSerializer<T>
    {
        public static T Deserialize(string type)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            var result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(type));

            return result;
        }

        public static string Serialize(T type)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            string originalMessage;

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(ms, type);
                ms.Position = 0;
                var document = new XmlDocument();
                document.Load(ms);

                originalMessage = document.OuterXml;
            }

            return originalMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think thet one way to read sequentially all elements in the SortedList is enumerating them one by one using `foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Data> kvp in _list) { // serialize an element }`

Comment: you can implement your own custom Dictionary that extends the existing one and is serializable, have a look here  http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx