# Serializable Class creation

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have to create an serializable class which has and xml in the format mentioned below. Please check the xml on this link and the ExtendedAttribute Element.

http://telligent.com/community/developers/w/developer6/update-a-user.aspx

The following tag is formed as and key value pair and does not have an object

My ExtendedAtribute class is not a fixed class but its an key value type object which may increase and decrease dynamically

Comment: You need to tidy that up, it's unreadable.

Comment: Put your xml into a file, say, `my.xml`, then - at the command line: xsd my.xml xsd my.xsd /classes And then `my.cs` has the code. Or just write the class manually: public class ExtendedAttributes { public bool EnableDisplayName {get;set;} ... public int CPPageSize {get;set;} ... In either case, use `new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExtendedAttributes)).Serialize(...)` etc.

Comment: my ExtendedAtribute class is not a fixed class but its an key value type object which may increase and decrease dynamically

Comment: @Selwyn then why are you asking about classes? Just use a DOM

Comment: i had used seriaziable classes for each of the elements only for the ExtendedAtrribute i havent used can you please help me how can i extract these dynamic element attributes

Comment: @Selwyn I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: Ah, I see, you have a list of attributes that may be bool, equivalent to Dictionary<string, bool> and you want to know how to serialise and dessrialise that such that the keys are the elements and the values the content of the elements?

Comment: I have seriaziable classes for each of the elements and i use xml seriaziable to deserialize the object but my major issue is for the extended properties since they are in the key value pair form tags that are dynamic and i could not deserialized to a fixed seriaziable class did i clear your doubt

Comment: @JonB yes you got it right ..

Comment: Do you need both directions or just to deserialise?

Comment: both but the deserialize is the the one i need the most since its a road block

Comment: I think it's a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495647/serialize-class-containing-dictionary-member See the top answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reduced XML File:-

```
<ExtendedAttributes>
  <EnableDisplayName>True</EnableDisplayName>
  <EditorType>Enhanced</EditorType>
  <EnableConversationNotifications>True</EnableConversationNotifications>
  <EnableUserSignatures>True</EnableUserSignatures>
  <CPPageSize>10</CPPageSize>
  <EnableActivityMessageNewUserAvatar>True</EnableActivityMessageNewUserAvatar>
  <EnableActivityMessageThirdPartyMessageType>True</EnableActivityMessageThirdPartyMessageType>
  <EnableStartConversations>1</EnableStartConversations>
  <avatarUrl>~/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-selectableavatars/03b2c875-fbfb-4d26-8000-ef001b9f4728/avatar.png</avatarUrl>
  <EnableActivityMessageNewProfileComment>False</EnableActivityMessageNewProfileComment>
  <EnableActivityMessageStatus>True</EnableActivityMessageStatus>
</ExtendedAttributes>
```

You can parse it with:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

  [XmlRoot("ExtendedAttributes")]
  public class SerialisableDictionary : Dictionary<string, string>, IXmlSerializable
  {
    #region IXmlSerializable Members
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
      return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
      reader.Read();
      while (reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement)
      {
        string key = reader.Name;
        this.Add(key, reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
        reader.MoveToElement();
      }
      reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
      // TODO
    }
    #endregion
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      SerialisableDictionary sd = new SerialisableDictionary();
      XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(sd.GetType());
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"XMLFile1.xml"))
      {
        sd = (SerialisableDictionary)x.Deserialize(sr);
      }
      foreach(var kvp in sd)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " = " + kvp.Value);
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Done.");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
```

This gives you a `Dictionary<string, string>` you almost certainly want the true/false/string/number values parsed, but that's another problem.

I appreciate this isn't perfect, but it should be enough to get you going. Unfortunately it will get quite involved and I don't have much time.

All based heavily on the answer in [Serialize Class containing Dictionary member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495647/serialize-class-containing-dictionary-member)

Comment: Thanks it worked for me and I am able to go ahead with my work,Thanks once again for the detailed code .

Comment: @Selwyn, glad to be of assistance.