# PostAsJsonAsync cannot serialize an object in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a couple code which is responsible to post some data to web api. And I am trying to post a Dictionary. But the key property cannot be serialized when the request is posted.

There is my code :

```
response = await base.HttpClientInstance.PostAsJsonAsync<Dictionary<ItemDto, string>>(url, dummyItems);
```

There is fiddler session summary :

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: debug.foo.foo.com
Content-Length: 78
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"Foo.Contract.Items.ItemDto":"87a0a711-6ecb-4ef5-9aed-04f7573344e1"}
```

Where is the problem, any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize Class containing Dictionary member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495647/serialize-class-containing-dictionary-member)

Comment: You can't easily serialize class implementing the `IDictionary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears at first glance that you need to override `ToString` in your `ItemDto` implementation ... the default implementation from the system is to just print the name of the class, e.g., `Foo.Contract.Items.ItemDto`.

Comment: Yes. But my expectation from PostAsJsonAsync method is serializing all properties properly. Actually it can be solved via your approaching. We can serialize itself in ToString method. Thanks :)

Comment: `HttpClientInstance` posting is just talking HTML, which is all text-based: it can't know how you want to "stringify" your `ItemDto`, so it relies on you to tell it by overriding `ToString`.  [**Accepting Answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).