# How to serialize XML without writing the type as a tag

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to write out an XML file, by serializing my class. The class includes a `dictionary<string,object>` called OptionList, and I have used some code I found here on Stack Overflow to create a serializable dictionary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1728996/3364648

However, it's not quite giving me what I want. After tweaking the code slightly, I'm getting closer. My WriteXml now looks like this:

```
    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

        foreach (TKey key in this.Keys)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Option");

            keySerializer.Serialize(writer, key);

            writer.WriteStartElement("value");
            TValue value = this[key];
            valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
```

and outputs this:

```
  <OptionList>
    <Option>
      <string>UNCOMMITTED</string>
      <value>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</anyType>
      </value>
    </Option>
    <Option>
      <string>DEADLOCK</string>
      <value>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</anyType>
      </value>
    </Option>
  </OptionList>
```

What I want as output is this:

```
  <OptionList>
    <Option>
      <key>UNCOMMITTED</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</value>
    </Option>
    <Option>
      <key>DEADLOCK</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</value>
    </Option>
  </OptionList>
```

Any ideas on how to replace `<string>` with `<key>` and `<anytype>` with `<value>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    foreach (TKey key in this.Keys)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Option");

        writer.WriteElementString("key", key.ToString());

        TValue value = this[key];
        writer.WriteElementString("value", value.ToString());

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

No need serializer. Do work manual.