# How to Serialize a Dictionary<string,List<Custom Type>> to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

I have a custom class:

```
public class DicExpense
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Company { get; set; }        
}
```

Which I am putting into a dictionary like this:

```
  var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<DicExpense>>();
  dict.Add("Expense1",new List<DicExpense>())
  dict["Expense1"].Add(new DicExpense() {EmployeeName = "Sam", Comment = "something"})
  dict["Expense1"].Add(new DicExpense() {EmployeeName = "Sam", Comment = "something"})


  dict.Add("Expense2",new List<DicExpense>())
  dict["Expense2"].Add(new DicExpense() {EmployeeName = "John", Comment = "something"})
  dict["Expense2"].Add(new DicExpense() {EmployeeName = "John", Comment = "something"})
```

I want to serialize this to XML:

```
 <Expense>
 <key>Expense1</key>
 <EmployeeName>Sam</EmployeeName>
 <Comment>something</Comment>
 <EmployeeName>John</EmployeeName>
 <Comment>something</Comment>
 </Expense>
```

I am trying this:

```
 StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
 var writer = new StringWriter(output);

 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string,     List<DicExpense>>));
 serializer.Serialize(writer, records);
 Console.WriteLine(output);
```

But it does not work. Is there a way to serialize a it when you have a value that is a collection of custom type?

Comment: What is not working? Your expected xml formal will be invalid with more than 1 record.

Comment: Here you can find more details about serializing dictionaries with XmlSerializer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495647/serialize-class-containing-dictionary-member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to serialize/deserialize a type which uses `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, use `DataContractSerializer`:

```
 [DataContract(Name = "Expense")]
 public class DicExpense
 {       
    [DataMember]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string Company { get; set; }
  }

 var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<DicExpense>>();
 dict.Add("Expense1", new List<DicExpense>());
 dict["Expense1"].AddRange(new List<DicExpense>
 {
    new  DicExpense()
    {
        EmployeeName = "Sam",
        Company = "company1"
    },
    new DicExpense()
    {
        EmployeeName = "John",
        Company = "company1"
    }
 });

 dict.Add("Expense2", new List<DicExpense>());
 dict["Expense2"].AddRange(new List<DicExpense>
 {
     new DicExpense()
     {
         EmployeeName = "Smith",
         Company = "company2"
      },
      new DicExpense()
      {
         EmployeeName = "John",
         Company = "company2"
      }
 });

 var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, List<DicExpense>>));
 using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out))
 {
      serializer.WriteObject(writer, dict);
 }
```

Comment: The main issue is that Dictionaries cannot be serialized without some workaround. Generics is not the main reason behind it. DataContractSerializer will likely fail too.

Comment: @tdgtyugdyugdrugdr .. Edited

Comment: Thanks @Mike Debela That works, but the output is a bit all convoluted.