# Get object from parent class object

Tags: c#

I have class

```
public class IPTable : SerializableDictionary<string, string>
{
...
}
```

trying to deserialize `IPTable`:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, string>));
StreamReader textReader = new StreamReader(xmlFileName);
SerializableDictionary<string, string> ip =( SerializableDictionary < string, string>) serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
return (IPTable)ip;
```

Got exception below while casting `SerializableDictionary<string, string>` to `IPTable`.

```
Message = "Unable to cast object of type 'SerializableDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' to type 'IPTable'."
```

How to deserialize to `IPTable`?

Comment: You're telling your serializer to serialize it as a `SerializableDictionary<string, stri` ... XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableDictionary<string, string>));.

Comment: You cannot serialize a dictionary (see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495647/serialize-class-containing-dictionary-member)  You can manually parse the xml using either XDocument or XmlDocument.

Comment: @jdweng You can serialize a `SerializableDictionary` though https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg496181.aspx The fact that the exception message says "Unable to cast object of type 'SerializableDictionary2[System.String,System.String]' to type 'IPTable'." means it's already successfully deserialized the `SerializableDictionary`.

Comment: Andy : Count it mean that the dictionary should be defined as : SerializableDictionary<string, List<string>>

Comment: "Unable to cast object of type `SerializableDictionary2[System.String,System.String]` to type `IPTable`." means "I have an object of the type `SerializableDictionary2[System.String,System.String]`, but I can't cast it in to an object of type `IPTable`".

Answer (score 3):

Create your `XmlSerializer` with `IPTable`

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IPTable));
StreamReader textReader = new StreamReader(xmlFileName);
return (IPTable)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
```