# How to serialize/deserialize to `Dictionary<int,List<string>>` from custom XML

Tags: c#, serialization

```
[Browsable(false)]
[XmlArray("CommonRows"), XmlArrayItem("Row", typeof(string))]
public List<string> CommonRows { get; set; }
```

I am Serializing list, after converting it getting the output in below XML format.

```
<CommonRows>
        <Row>3</Row>
        <Row>5</Row>
        <Row>7</Row>
        <Row>9</Row>
</CommonRows>
```

How to do I make Dictionary serializable.

```
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> CommonRows { get; set; }
```

I am trying to get the output in this way

```
<dictionary>
  <item>
    <key>
      <string>key1</string>
    </key>
    <value>
      <string>value1</string>
      <string>value1</string>
      <string>value1</string>
    </value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <key>
      <string>key1</string>
    </key>
    <value>
        <string>value2</string>
        <string>value2</string>
        <string>value2</string>
        <string>value2</string>
    </value>
  </item>
</dictionary>
```

Please suggest how to serialized in this way?

Answer (score 0):

The XmlSerializer cannot process classes implementing the IDictionary interface.
Please check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx)

In MSDN documentation, there is Q and A:

Q: Why can't I serialize hashtables?

A: The XmlSerializer cannot process classes implementing the IDictionary interface. This was partly due to schedule constraints and partly due to the fact that a hashtable does not have a counterpart in the XSD type system. The only solution is to implement a custom hashtable that does not implement the IDictionary interface.

Similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495647/serialize-class-containing-dictionary-member).